# Draw lines on a image and zoom it all

Tags: java, swing, zooming, draw, paintcomponent

From another class I load a image, which represents a map, using JFileChooser. In the new frame, I will have the image, I will load data for the images (like the coordinates of the corners), and after that I need to draw the distance on the map and zoom that image with the lines on it.

The problem I have is that the paintComponent function doesn't show me anything, it doesn't even go into it (I try to load it using menubar). And the next problem is that I don't know exactly how I should zoom in on the image with the drawn distances.

At this moment I only have the image with the map and the zoom applied to it.

I have an actionPerformed for an item from menubar:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
...
 if(e.getSource()==addR)
{
         add( new RoutePane());

     }
 }
```

The RoutePane class is ():

```
   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
class RoutePane extends JPanel{
     @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
               Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) g;
               int x=10;
              gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
              for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                gr.drawLine(x,x,x+10,x+10);
                x+=10;
           }

     }
     @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(1200, 700);
      }
}
```

The zoom method that I have is from this website: (https://coderanch.com/t/338284/java/zoom-zoom-picture-swing)

Comment: Do you expect the RoutePane to draw the image? If so, shouldn't that class hold a reference to the image of interest and then draw it within paintComponent? I'm not sure where you're stuck, where your attempt code is supposed to be.

Comment: The image is displayed using the code from the website that I mentioned. Basically, when I initially generate the image using that code, to be able to view it. If I load it normally, using drawImage, it won't show it all to me (the size of one of the images I have is width: 5549 and height: 7798).I would like RoutePane to draw only the lines over what I have (the image that already has the functional zoom).

Comment: If RoutePane is to draw only lines, then it shouldn't extend JPanel. Instead it should contain only logic for drawing lines, say a `public void draw(Graphics2D g)` method that you give it and that is called by the drawing JPanel. Only ***one*** JPanel in the application should be responsible for drawing everything. Everything else involved with drawing should be non-component classes.

Comment: Note that for better help, you will want to create and post a new separate program with your question, a [mre]. I recommend that you read the link and see how it can help you get an answer here. Also, focus on a single question, as you appear to be asking 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I managed to draw the line over the image. I need to see now how to adjust the line when I use zooming.
I asked 2 questions in the same place because these parts should be linked together. Thank you also for the advice about how to write the questions. I will consider it from now on.